# Android CalendarView height does not match_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-calendar

I want to use `CalendarView` full screen like this code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But this view height looks `wrap_content` on device.

[image]

Is there any full screen `CalendarView` in github ? I don't find any - or Can I make this view really `match_parent` .

any suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: It has a fixed content size, you can't make it bigger without scaling on the X axis as well

Comment: I dont know how can I make bigger with scaling on the X axis . Can you share some code .

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">


    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/dengshiwei/CalendarComponent

in MonthView

```
@override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST){
widthSize = (int) (300 * density);
}
if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST){
heightSize = (int) density * 200;
}
if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST){
widthSize = (int) density * 300;
}
width = widthSize;
NUM_ROWS = 10; 

setMeasuredDimension(widthSize, heightSize);
}
```

this code above make calendarview height match_parent . Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way . hope this will help.

Calendar will look like this.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    </CalendarView>

</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```